# How to make input placeholder text editable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app I want to edit data in an input field but without having to retype everything that's already there. I can populate the data for each field into the placeholder text but it's not editable and disappears when you start typing. Is there a way of making this a default editable value?

Sorry if this has been answered before – it seems basic to me but I've searched high and low and just can't find the answer I'm looking for.

```
import React from 'react'
import { EditIcon, MenuIcon } from '../icons'

import {
    TableCell,
    TableRow,
    Button,
    Input,
  } from '@windmill/react-ui'

export class Transaction extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      editView: false
    }
    this.onEditButtonClicked = this.onEditButtonClicked.bind(this)
  }

  onEditButtonClicked(){
    this.setState({
      editView: !this.state.editView
    })
  }

  render() {
    const editClicked = this.state.editView

    if (editClicked) {
      return (
        <TableRow key={this.props.transaction.id}>
          <TableCell>
            <Input 
              className="text-sm"
              placeholder={this.props.transaction.payee}
            />
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
              <Button aria-label="Delete" block size="small">
                Save
              </Button>
              <Button layout="outline" aria-label="Cancel" onClick={this.onEditButtonClicked} block size="small">
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </div>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      )
    }

    return (
      <TableRow key={this.props.transaction.id}>
          <TableCell>
            <p className="text-sm">{this.props.transaction.payee}</p>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
              <Button layout="link" size="icon" aria-label="Edit" onClick={this.onEditButtonClicked}>
                <EditIcon className="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" />
              </Button>
            </div>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: then you should give a `default value` to your text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you described called value, not a placeholder. So, just use a value and set a default value for this.

More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: Thought it would be simple. Thank you!